# How to pass a stack from one activity to another in android studio

Tags: java, android, data-structures, stack

I am trying to pass a stack from one activity to another in android studio.

Currently I have a stack called:
`Stack<Integer> teamAstack = new Stack<>();`

And I am passing it like this:

```
                public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameReview.class);
                intent.putExtra("stack1",teamAstack);        
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

From what I have looked online to pass objects I need to do it like this?

Receiving Activity

`getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stack1");`

I initially tried setting it equal to a new stack which I made in the new activity but it says the types are different, with one being a stack and the other being serializable. I am unsure what do to to pass the stack correctly so that I can start popping and pushing from the new activity, thanks for all your help! There was nothing specifically for stacks on all my searches which is why I am having this issue.

New Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Stack;

public class GameReview extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_review);

    Stack<Integer> stack11 = (Stack<Integer>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stack1");
    Stack<Integer> stack22 = (Stack<Integer>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stack2");

}
}
```

Comment: yes, what you do is correct, you just need to cast: `Stack<Integer> stack = (Stack<Integer>) intent.getSerializableExtra("stack1");` - tells Java that you are sure it's a certain subtype of `Serializable`, a `Stack<Integer>` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stack1");` you get an object of type `Serializable` since you know this object is of type `Stack<Integer>` you can cast it and store it in a variable

`Stack<Integer> stack = (Stack<Integer>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stack1");`

Comment: Sweet I understand how it should work now logically, but it keeps crashing when I try to go to this activity, and I think it is something on this page because if I put no code on it it doesn't crash. There are only two lines of code on the activity so I am unsure what is wrong. The new activity code is edited on the main post, I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Is "stack2" also passed the same way? And what is the error?

Comment: Yea its passed the same way, but theres no error it just doesn't load the screen and goes back to a different activity but if I comment out the code it goes to the correct activity so something there is wrong but I don't see it.